# strikes glimmers

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the exact meaning of "struck glimmers" in the following passage?

The moon struck glimmers from the cross and ring of the Apostolic Delegate.

Thanks a million.

Comment: You haven't cited the source, but _glimmer_ could be a "a faint or wavering light.", and _strike_ could mean something like "to strike a match".

Comment: A light can figuratively strike (produce) reflections as a hammer strikes sparks from a piece of metal.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Your comment is the basis of an answer. Glimmers are all to do with light, especially flickering, unsteady and unpredictable little flashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the physical light rays of the moon "strike" or "hit" the surface of "the cross and ring". By the physical properties of light and the objects, the rays are not absorbed but rather reflected such that the narrator of the passage is at the capacity to see said light rays. This is what is meant by the "glimmers" - the visible phenomenon of reflection.